# Android Studio: "Error initializing ADB: Android Debug Bridge not found"

Tags: android, sdk, ide

I've installed Android Studio 3.0, and have compiled and run applications successfully.

Device File explorer pane has the above error message in red, and nothing else.

Answer (score 27):

Each Android Studio project requires information as to what SDK is to be used, and where it is located. The overall configuration defined in the SDK Manager under the tools menu is not enough, and it is used seemly to download and install the necessary SDK, so

- make sure you have Android SDK installed.
- Now opened or create a project (open an APK file for instance),
- then follow these steps to define the SDK for the project:

  1. Under **File -> Project Structure**, select **SDKs** under **Platform Settings**.
  2. If you don't have an **Android SDK** item in the right next pane, then click on the green `+` to add one. Give it a name of **Android SDK**,
  3. and edit the path to `c:\users\yourusername\appdata\local\android\sdk` (or the actual location as defined under SDK Manager).
  4. Next, still under **Project Settings**, select **Project**, and
  5. in the right next pane under "Project SDK" select the new project SDK that you just created.
  6. Save.

Your project is configured. Now open task manager and kill any existing `adb.exe` processes. Android Studio is now ready to work with ADB.

Test by opening the **Device File Explorer** (this is a vertical tab on the very right bottom edge of AS), or test by selecting the **Attach debugger** to **Android Process** button, and you should see your Android Device.

If ADB doesn't communicate with your Android device, check to see if you have installed the **Android USB driver**. Also, the phone needs to be in developer mode for ADB to work with it.

Last point, I have had more success with AS/ADB when I launch AS with *Administrator* privileges. I hope this information is helpful to someone.

Comment: It would seem you are new to the site. Your answers would be more appealing if they would be a little better formatted. For example, splitting paragraphs were convenient; presenting steps as enumerated or bulleted lists; using **bold**, _italics_, `code`, etc for highlighting terms and emphasizing ideas or concepts.

Comment: Yeah I'm with @hanzo2001 on this.

Comment: The problem I had on a new PC/install was that these settings (copied over from the old PC) needed to be updated to match the SDK I actually had installed.

Answer (score 9):

***Solution of Android Debug Bridge not found.***

Simple following 4 Steps :

1. Open *File* -> *Project Structure* -> *Project*

   • see if SDK not Selected..

   [image]
2. Select any latest SDK *OR* Select Supported version for your system.

   [image]
3. Then Open *File* -> *Invalid Caches OR Restart* Select.

   [image]
4. You can See ADB Error Goes and Emulators Function on the Screen.

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

You might not have installed the ADB drivers. It must be causing the IDE error to occur. 
Try to install the ADB (Google USB Drivers from the Android SDK Manager provided in Android Studio).