# Error initializing ADB: Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start ADB server

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

When no other of these questions are helping me, then this means I need to remove and reinstall Android Studio.

Here's the error:

> Error initializing ADB: Unable to create Debug Bridge:
> Unable to start ADB server: adb server version (36) doesn't match this client;
> killing... could not read OK from ADB server

- failed to start daemon error:
  cannot connect to daemon 'C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary.

Comment: After hours of searching and no results, I found the solution on MacOS by accident. Hit `cmd + ;` and I was met with a screen with a red "no sdk" dropdown. Filling that in with the existing Android API made it all work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647530/unable-to-run-adb-exe-from-platform-tools-folder-path/62911890#62911890

Answer (score 94, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions depending on what exactly is causing the problem.

So, just follow the following steps.

***Step 1:-*** Close Android-Studio.
***Step 2:-*** Open Command prompt *or <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>*.
***Step 3:-*** Navigate to your `platform-tools`, in most of the cases the location is:

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

but in your case, the location is:

```
C:\Android\Sdk\
```

For Mac users the path is

```
/Users/[user]/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

***Step 4:-*** Type `adb.exe start-server`, Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
***Step 5:-*** Open Android Studio again.

For Mac the command is just `adb start-server`

The problem should be solved!

---

If the problem persists, then follow these steps-

***Step 1:-*** Close Android Studio.
***Step 2:-*** Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>, then choose `Start Task Manager`.

*Windows Task Manager opens.*

***Step 3:-*** Go to the `processes` tab.
***Step 4:-*** Look for `adb.exe` and select that.
***Step 5:-*** Press `End Process`.
***Step 6:-*** Open Android Studio again.

That's it. Now your problem must be solved!

---

But if the problem is still there (which I don't think will happen), then there is something wrong (or might be missing) in your `platform-tools`.

To fix that, delete `platform-tools` from your computer, then download them again from [Official Android Developer website.](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html#tos-header)

Extract the downloaded file.

Now place the extracted file, where `platform-tools` were located before deleting.

Default Location of `platform-tools` is

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\
```

But in your case, the location is

```
C:\Android\Sdk\
```

Comment: With me, I solved by uninstall Universal Adb Driver

Comment: This works like a charm, but is this should be done every time we start the emulator?

Comment: Sadly none of the three options worked for me and now I think it is because mine is company's laptop. I know that does not make sense.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70223806/3139779 Here is something which helped me. Posting for future devs

Comment: After trying a lot of solution , this solution works for me

Comment: I'm also getting this error when opening my Jetpack Compose project on my Surface tablet (I mainly use my desktop PC to do development). It used to work so I'm not sure what happened.

Mine also says "Process did not terminate within specified timeout, killing it: 'C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.20f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary"

I do have Unity installed on here too but I'm not sure where Android Studio, or my project, is getting that path from. Trying the solutions above did not work.

Answer (score 12):

I spent around a complete day to look for the solution but couldn't find the exact one.

**Finally what I did was that I uninstalled my antivirus and after that it worked like a charm.**

So, here I shortlist the steps to check whether you are solving for the correct problem or not:-

1. Run command prompt and set path to where adb.exe file is present. (In most of the cases it's found at C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools)
2. Type `adb start-server` and press enter.
3. If there is an error displayed saying something like "Cannot connect to daemon" , then you must look in your antivirus for firewall settings and add the path to its exceptions or you can simply uninstall your antivirus.

Comment: After trying so many steps I found the solution in step 3 of your answer. After uninstalling the antivirus it works fine.

Answer (score 12):

Steps to follow for Immediate recovery.

No need to close Android Studio.

1. Goto Task Manager By Clicking **(Ctrl + Shift + Esc)**.
2. Open **Processes Tab**.
3. Click Image Name in the Processes Tab for Ascending Order(A-Z).
4. Now choose **adb.exe** (or) **adb.exe*32** (or) **adb.exe*64**.
5. Now Click **End Process** Button at Right End Bottom corner.
6. That's All , Now your adb will auto re-started When Launching Application.

Answer (score 6):

Download, extract and replace the platform-tools folder with this one [here](https://androidstudio.io/downloads/tools/download-the-latest-version-of-adb.exe.html) because the adb.exe file could be corrupted or empty with a file size of 0KB

File path on **windows**

```
C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

File path on **mac**

```
/Users/[user]/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 4):

on MacOS, I kill all adb process in Activity Monitor. Its working...

Answer (score 2):

On my Macbook,  I had to kill an already running server from the terminal to fix the problem:

```
josh@JoshsMBP ~ % ps aux | grep adb 
josh             19134   2.5  0.0  4421320   5216   ??  Ss   31Aug21 229:41.25 adb -L tcp:5037 fork-server server --reply-fd 4
josh             93496   0.8  0.0  4279728    816 s000  S+    1:47pm   0:00.00 grep adb
josh@JoshsMBP ~ % pkill adb
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes due to antivirus treating adb as malware sometimes

**Solution 1**

- Close the android studio
- End task background process adb.exe()/
  adb.exe(32)/ adb.exe(64) from Task Manager.
- Relaunch android studio.

**Solution 2**

- open cmd (administrator mode) ...\Android\sdk\platform-tools on this path and
  run the following commands:
- adb.exe kill-server
- adb.exe start-server