# Unable to run adb.exe from platform-tools folder path

Tags: android

Setup

- android studio version 3.3.2
- JRE:1.8.0-152-release-1248-b01-amd64
- build tool version is 28.0.2

I am unable to start `adb.exe` file from `platform-tools` in sdk folder .
Error popping in taskbar of android studio is "unable to detect adb version,adb output".
When i run `adb.exe` application from SDK folder error is---->The Application was unable to start correctly(0xc000007b).---------

I had reinstall android studio many times. also deleted the platform-tools folder and re-downloaded Android sdk platform-tools. sdk  platform tool 
[image]

Comment: tried to open terminal window and lauch `adb.exe` from the command line?

Answer (score 16):

I found a solution after spending the 3 day. Replace your current adb with another working adb. [Click here to download adb.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kpA3pkmkSdNzf_wwJd5EFgCKA3iWSizy/view)

## Steps:->

**1>** First  **download adb**  file for the above link .
**2>** To add **adb file** in **platform-tools** inside **Sdk** folder in android studio.

3> Open  **Android Studio** and go to **Tools** and inside Tools there is a **SDK Manager.**
click on **SDK Manager** as shown below:--

4> Copy the **Android SDK Location address** (path is as like  as **C:\Users\APPPPPPPPPPPPPPP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk** )  shown below

5>  Search the copy address in the **search bar** of  **Windows OS**,then a **Platform-Tools** folder is show under **Sdk** folder.

6> Open the **Platform-Tools**  delete the existing **adb.exe** file and add the downloaded **adb.exe** file is pasted in the **Platform-tools** folder.

After placing the **adb.exe** file.Open **Android Studio** and create a  **new project**  of use **existing project** and click on **Run** in the **menu bar or Run button** and you see  that in **Event Log** the **error** of **unable to detect adb version,adb output** is removed and you successfully run the project  either by using AVD emulator OR Real devices like android smartphones.

Comment: The adb at the download link is for 32 bit operating systems

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this error with next step:

1. -> Open **Android Studio** -> open **SDK Manager** and see where is location **SDK** 
      folder, most often is: **C:\Users\Toshiba\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk**, then 
      shutdown **Android Studio**,
2. -> Open **\platform-tools** folder and try run **adb.exe**. If you cant open or get 
      any message error like this: ***api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll is missing***
3. -> go on this [site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/download/details.aspx?id=48145&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True) download and install **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual 
     Studio 2015** (*32- and 64-bit versions*)
4. -> Open **Windows Explorer** and right click **“My PC”**. Select **“Properties”**
5. -> Select **“Advanced System Settings”** -> select **“Environment Variables”** -> and
      upon System variable click on **NEW**: Variable name: **PATH** and Variable value: 
       **C:\Users\Toshiba\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk** -> OK
6. -> **Restart PC** and **run** Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue in a heartbeat by downloading the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019.

Specifically the file `x64: vc_redist.x64.exe` from this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

I ran into this issue when I reformatted my Windows PC and the redistributables that came with the new installation were versions 2008, 2005, and 2010.

Answer (score 0):

That error code refers to an invalid image format. However, what the error code usually means is that you are trying to run a program that is intended to work with a 64 bit Windows operating system, but that you only have a 32 bit OS.

Try restarting your computer and see if it works.
If it doesn't work, try to uninstall and reinstall the program by going into Control Panel>Classic View>add/remove programs or program and features.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution,

1) close Android Studio.

1) Delete the folder name **platform-tools** from Sdkfolder(find path from SDK Manager) folder.

2) Open Android Studio, in SDK Manager -> SDK Tools. checked the checkBox of Android Sdk Plateform-Tools and Apply.

3) now, Restart Android studio and try again.

Comment: then download plateform-tools version 28.0.1 from and replace this  https://www.teamandroid.com/2017/05/06/download-adb-fastboot-android-sdk-platform-tools/

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was the installation of visual studio C++ redistributable. I tried to install it but was getting a setup failed error. Apparently, i had to go to windows update and allow all the important updates (the ones listed as important).

After restarting, i was able to install C++ redistributable. After it was installed, adb.exe worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is showing error because Android ADB had an update for the revision 28.0.2 (March 2019), after this release ADB needs windows to have this update (KB2999226) for running. This will be occurring to systems that disabled automatic windows update. For me, it was on Windows 8.1 pro 64. I have spent my 2 days on this following different solutions on the internet that vary from DLL files to .net, visual c++, and DirectX, none of them helped. Please do this update as this is needed for the newer ADB to work properly.

[Android revision change having notification about this](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools#2802_march_2019)

[Link to the update for windows 8.1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue for downloading or Update for **Universal C Runtime in Windows.**

First, check your operating system is how many bits example 64-bit operating system.

**Control Panel --> All Control Panel Items --> System**

then below link to download your operating system specific version and install the **Universal C Runtime in Windows.**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

solve a problem and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

It Worked , in my case platform-tool was broken so i downloaded [platform-tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools?authuser=2) from Google and replaced existing in c/ folder. after this run adb.exe and restart Android Studio. Happy Coding