# adb.exe unable to start

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I cant see my android Devices in android studio (3.5).  So I Start troubleshoot  device connection. But it can't find any android devices but find 15 devices that not recognized as android devices, but my android device HUAWEI Y336-U02 shown their.
[troubleshoot  device connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4PNf.png)

Then I open cmd and run adb.exe form android sdk platform-tools but it showing Error

```
adb.exe the application was unable to start correctly(0xc000007b)
```

How to resolve this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to run adb.exe from platform-tools folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647530/unable-to-run-adb-exe-from-platform-tools-folder-path)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647530/unable-to-run-adb-exe-from-platform-tools-folder-path/62911890#62911890