# I have an error initializing ADB : Android debud bridge not found message on my mac . What should i do?

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to connect my android phone to my android studio via my macbook but the android studio keeps displaying the “Error initializing ADB: Android Debug Bridge not found” message.

Please let me know on what i should do .

thanks

Comment: Try this: The following solution may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340436/error-initializing-adb-unable-to-create-debug-bridge-unable-to-start-adb-serve

Comment: this helped me solve the problem . thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go to File>Invalidate Caches and Restart.

After restart, in the terminal write the command `adb devices`. If you get the error, as you mentioned then that means you don't have adb installed. But as far as I have used Android Studio, you don't get this error in Linux and Mac.

Also if you are trying to connect to your physical phone, then you need to enable Developer Options, and then **check** *enable USB Debugging*.