# Android Studio ADB not Found error Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

When ı workıng on databases (sqflite 1.3.0) ı created a db file in my project and when ı want to check it
when ı clicked to device file explorer ı took this Error initializing ADB:Android Debug Bridge not found.
Do u have any advice for solving this problem?

everything is normal in  flutter doctor sdk updated platform tools updated adc.exe closed and opened deleted updated.[image is here u can see from here 
[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RBqh.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49345049/9142279

Comment: it didnt work ı tried ty