# I can't run my Android Studio project on a real Android device

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, debugging, kotlin-android-extensions

When I tried to run my Android Studio project on my Android phone using a USB cable, Android Studio shows this message:

> Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to
> detect adb version, exit value: 0xc000007b

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340436/error-initializing-adb-unable-to-create-debug-bridge-unable-to-start-adb-serve

Answer (score 3):

In order to use physical device, follow these steps :

1. Open settings and go to About phone -> Go to Build number and tap it until a toast
   appears as you are in developer mode.
2. Go to developer mode and enable USB Debugging.
3. Connect your phone to pc via USB cable.
4. Wait for your device to be appear next to run button in android studio.
5. If it appears, simply run otherwise in your android device choose use USB to :
   Transfer file or ptp.

Comment: If you have already follows above steps then  I would recommend you to visit this, if problem still persist : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340436/error-initializing-adb-unable-to-create-debug-bridge-unable-to-start-adb-serve.