# error initializing ADB : unable to create debug bridge : unable to start ADB server

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

i have problem in my android studio using windows , the error like :" error initializing ADB : unable to create debug bridge : unable to start ADB server :unable to detect adb version
how can i fix this ?
thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340436/error-initializing-adb-unable-to-create-debug-bridge-unable-to-start-adb-serve ?

Answer (score 0):

Download, extract and replace the platform-tools folder by following these steps given in link https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb because the adb.exe file could be corrupted or empty with a file size of 0KB

File path on windows

C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools