# Why is my Android Studio not functioning properly?

Tags: android-studio

I'm having a lot of trouble since I installed Android Studio to learn Android Programming.

I'm getting an error message like this and even my Pallete is not being displayed.

[image]

Please help me solve this error. Sorry if the way of asking this question is ridiculous cause I'm new here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: "Error initializing ADB: Android Debug Bridge not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506261/android-studio-error-initializing-adb-android-debug-bridge-not-found)

Answer (score -1):

Download ALL SDK Tools and restart your android studio